# External Flash Only Fires Once

Tags: nikon, flash

Weird problem - Setup is as follows: D5600 -> Pixel TF-322 hotshoe to sync cable adapter -> Flashpoint FPBF120 strobe.

The strobe only fires the first time I hit the shutter button; after that, the camera takes a shot, but the strobe doesn't fire. The strobe has an LED indicator and emits an audible beep when it's recharged, so not an issue of insufficient recharge time.

If I unplug the sync cable and short the contacts w/ a pair of tweezers, the strobe fires reliably every time. Power cycling the strobe allows it to again fire a single shot. The strobe also triggers reliably in slave mode, using the on-camera flash as the master.

Not sure if I should be looking at the camera, the adapter, or the strobe itself for the problem. Can't find any menu options on the D5600 that seem to be relevant.

Will grab a multimeter and probe the contacts of the hot shoe to see what's going on, but thought this might be an issue someone's encountered before.

Comment: I'm suspecting that you are on some auto exposure mode.  Try manual and see if this changes anything.  (A preflash shouldn't be firing on manual)

Comment: Oops, that's an important point I missed - all settings are manual. Camera is mounted on a bellows, no lens communication (the D5600 reads 'no lens attached' and won't fire in any other mode).

Comment: It is an incompatibility between the camera and adapter or the adapter and the flash. I would try a different adapter. My favorite adapter, a Wein Safe Sync, doesn't seem to be sold anymore. This technical article probably has more detail than you care to know. Either the camera or the adapter can have the SCR component that is likely not being reset. This would be a good question for the Electrical Engineering SE if you had schematics.  https://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/how-to-reset-scr-used-for-triggering-camera-flash.17891/

Comment: Thanks for the info! I've got a feeling you're right. Took apart the adapter last night, plenty of room in there to dead-bug in an RC circuit. I'll have to dig around to find the right cap (almost exclusively work w/ SMD components now), but I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: Since it flashes again with a mechanical short, it could be that your camera's trigger circuit isn't a low enough impedance. Since you seem to be electronically handy, perhaps you can get the camera to close a small relay (like a reed switch) to see if that works?